# cmake Look for the opencv library

Tags: opencv, cmake

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzC1i.png)

Although, I set the new `OpenCV_DIR` variable but CMake is still preferentially finding opencv from vcpkg.

I want CMake to do a dependency lookup from a custom library directory.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for represent *textual* information. Instead, paste the code and output into the question post as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.